# How to write a custom precheck middleware for some of the endpoints?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a `asp dotnetcore` web service that exposes some endpoints. For some of the endpoints, I want to run a check if existing `scorecard` is visible. The endpoints urls are:

```
GET /api/v1/scorecard/{ScorecardId}/details

GET /api/v1/scorecard/{ScorecardId}/rankings
```

These endpoints are just examples but they could be tens in numbers. Each of these endpoints have their own handlers like:

```
public async Task<ScorecardDetails> Get(long scorecardId)
{}

public async Task<ScorecardRankings> Get(long scorecardId)
{}
```

In database, there is a table `Scorecard` that stores the scorecard details and has a column `IsVisible`. I want to return `404` for all calls to these `scorecard` endpoints for scorecards that are set `IsVisible = False` in database.

Comment: You server is getting a URL like "/api/v1/scorecard/{ScorecardId}/details"  Your server endpoint is "/api/v1/scorecard" and you then need to get rest of URL to extract the parameter like "{ScorecardId}/details".  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=windows

Comment: don't worry about how the complete url is mapped to handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should consider using `IActionFilter` and `IAsyncActionFilter` for this purpose. In there you have a chance to read the already bound-model for parameters to better validate it. Of course that way has its own complexity unless you accept the way in which we decorate ***every*** parameters on every methods that require to check the existence of objects. That way is fairly inconvenient but to make it convenient, you need to design a model to allow you to declare (setup or configure) your targeted endpoints as well as how to target the required parameters for the existence checking process.

Here I introduce the way of using a middleware, just like what you want originally. It sounds more convenient than using action filters but it has its own complexity and inconvenience. At the phase of the middleware, we don't have any data bound to parameters and even not any `RouteData` available yet. That means we need to parse for the route values (here only the object's id) from the path. Parsing is a complex job especially when we need to make it fast. However I think using `Regex` for this purpose here is acceptable (although the framework code does not seem to like using `Regex` for the best performance). The framework code has a much more strict requirement for performance because it's the platform we build everything on. But in your code, you can take tradeoff between performance and easy-to-implement.

First we need a custom middleware like this:

```
public class EnsureExistenceByIdFromRouteValuesMiddleware
{
    readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    readonly EnsureExistenceByIdFromRouteValuesOptions _options;
    public EnsureExistenceByIdFromRouteValuesMiddleware(RequestDelegate next,
                                                        EnsureExistenceByIdFromRouteValuesOptions options)
    {
        _next = next;
        _options = options;
    }
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var serviceType = _options.ExistenceCheckingServiceType;
        var routePatterns = _options.RoutePatterns;            
        if (serviceType != null && routePatterns != null && routePatterns.Count > 0)
        {
            var service = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService(_options.ExistenceCheckingServiceType) as IExistenceCheckingService;
            if (service != null)
            {
                var matchedRoute = routePatterns.Select(e => Regex.Match(context.Request.Path,
                                                                         e ?? "",
                                                                         RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase,
                                                                         TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)))
                                                .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Success);
                var id = matchedRoute?.Groups?.Skip(1)?.FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
                {
                    var isExisted = await service.ExistsAsync(id);
                    if (!isExisted && !context.Response.HasStarted)
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                        if (!_options.LetMvcHandle404)
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }                    
            }
        }
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

The associated options class:

```
public class EnsureExistenceByIdFromRouteValuesOptions
{
    public IList<string> RoutePatterns { get; } = new List<string>();
    public Type ExistenceCheckingServiceType { get; set; }
    public bool LetMvcHandle404 { get; set; }
    public EnsureExistenceByIdFromRouteValuesOptions AddRoutePattern(string pattern)
    {
        RoutePatterns.Add(pattern);
        return this;
    }
    public EnsureExistenceByIdFromRouteValuesOptions ClearRoutePatterns()
    {
        RoutePatterns.Clear();
        return this;
    }
}
```

Your services (for checking object existence) should implement a common & well-known interface (used by the middleware) like this:

```
public interface IExistenceCheckingService
{
    Task<bool> ExistsAsync(object id);
}

//this is a sample implementation (just for demo)
public class ExistenceCheckingService : IExistenceCheckingService
{
    public Task<bool> ExistsAsync(object id)
    {
        //dummy implementation for testing, only id of 1 is existed.
        return Task.FromResult(Equals(id, "1"));
    }
}
```

We create a convenient extension class for using in `Startup.ConfigureServices` and `Startup.Configure`:

```
public static class EnsureExistenceByIdFromRouteValuesExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection EnsureExistenceByIdFromRouteValues(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //configure the MvcOptions to add the custom middleware
        return services.Configure<MvcOptions>(o => {
            o.Filters.Add(new EnsureExistenceByIdFromRouteValuesActionFilter());
        }).AddScoped<IExistenceCheckingService, ExistenceCheckingService>();
    }

    public static IApplicationBuilder UseEnsureExistenceByIdFromRouteValuesMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder app,
        EnsureExistenceByIdFromRouteValuesOptions options)
    {
        if (options == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));
        return app.UseMiddleware<EnsureExistenceByIdFromRouteValuesMiddleware>(options);
    }

    public static IApplicationBuilder UseEnsureExistenceByIdFromRouteValuesMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder app, 
        Action<EnsureExistenceByIdFromRouteValuesOptions> configureOptions)
    {
        if (configureOptions == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configureOptions));

        var options = new EnsureExistenceByIdFromRouteValuesOptions();
        configureOptions(options);
        return app.UseEnsureExistenceByIdFromRouteValuesMiddleware(options);
    }
    //we use this filter for lately handling the 404 (set by the middleware)
    class EnsureExistenceByIdFromRouteValuesActionFilter : IActionFilter
    {
        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context) {}

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            if(context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 404)
            {
                context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(404);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use it in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.EnsureExistenceByIdFromRouteValues();
```

Use it in `Startup.Configure`:

```
app.UseEnsureExistenceByIdFromRouteValuesMiddleware(o => {
      //add your Regex patterns here
      o.AddRoutePattern("/scorecard/(\\d+)/details/?$");
      o.AddRoutePattern("/scorecard/(\\d+)/rankings/?$");

      o.ExistenceCheckingServiceType = typeof(IExistenceCheckingService);
      //setting this to true to not short-circuit right after the middleware
      //the MVC middleware next will handle this (in the action filter)
      //That way you will have a chance to use a custom view for 404
      //(otherwise such as for Web APIs, we can let this be false as by default).
      //o.LetMvcHandle404 = true;
});
```

***NOTE***: you need to know regex to use this. In the code above, I include just 2 sample regexes (matching your sample paths posted in your question). The regex patten ***must*** include one captured group for the *object id* (the `(\\d+)` in the sample patterns). That should be the first group (or should be the only group).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change the return type of the Get functions so that they can return a 404.

So:

```
public async Task<ScorecardDetails> Get(long scorecardId)
```

Becomes (pseudo-code):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(long scorecardId) {
    if(ScoreCardExists(scorecardId)) {
        ScorecardDetails details = GetDetails(scorecardId);
        return Ok(details);
    }else{
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```